Studying the irreducibility of polynomials

Given $K$ a field, study if the following polynomials are irreducible on $K[x,y]$ : $$f(x,y) = xy^4 + x^3 y^3 + x^2 (y^3 + 1) - 1 \\ g(x,y) = x^5 + y(x^4 + x^3 + y (y + 1) x + y) $$

I am trying to do this excercise from my book and I want to know if I am doing well.
In order to study $f$, we can see it as a polynomial $f_y$ on $K[y][x]$ by regrouping its terms: $$f_y (x) = y^3 x^3 + (y^3 + 1) x^2 + y^4 x - 1 $$
Know, I think that we can apply a criterion that says that a polynomial $p(t)$ is irreducible iff $\hat{p}(t) := t^{\deg(p)} \cdot p(\frac{1}{t})$ is also irreducible. In this case: $$\hat{f_y}(x) = - x^3 + y^4 x^2 + (y^3 + 1) x + y^3 $$
Now, we can observe that $\hat{f_y}$ is monic, so its zeros must divide $y^3$. But given $c \in K - \{0\}$ and $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ : $$\hat{f_y}(cy^k) = -c^3 y^{3k} + c^2 y^{4+2k} + c (y^3 + 1) y^k  + y^3 \neq 0$$
Therefore, $\hat{f_y}$ has no zeros on $K[y]$ and then it is irreducible, so $f_y$ is also irreducible.
I have problems to study $g$ since I do not find a criterion that suits. I have tried the same as for $f$, also the Eisenstein and the translation criterions but I do not reach anything, so any possible help or advice would be very appreciated.

For the conclusion that $f$ is irreducible you also use some fact about cubic polynomials and a fact about roots of monic polynomials over factorial rings. Maybe you know what you are doing here, but just saying.

For $g$ you write it as a cubic polynomial in $y$:
$$g = x y^3 + (x + 1) y^2 + (x^4 + x^3) y + x^5 \in K[x]\bigl[y\bigr].$$
Since this is of degree $3$ and $K[x]$ is factorial, it suffices to show that it has no roots in $K(x)$. The roots in $K(x)$ have the form $p/q$ where $p,q \in K[x]$ such that $p \mid x^5$ and $q \mid x$ (rational root theorem), and you can conclude from here.

I forgot that this can be applied on polynomials that are not monic, thanks!
